# Are there any models of computation currently being studied with the possibility of being more powerful than Turing Machines?

Tags: computability, physics, machine-models, natural-computing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What would it mean to disprove Church-Turing thesis?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/88/what-would-it-mean-to-disprove-church-turing-thesis)

Are there any models of computation currently being studied with the possibility of being more powerful than Turing Machines?

Comment: Yes. For instance, the **circuit model** (non-uniform Turing machines). But I don't think this is a research-level question, as per FAQ. You may ask it on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Sadeq Dousti: Thank you, but I am interested in uniform models. I want to learn about models which are being studied by researchers, doesn't that make it a research-level question?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable question to me, but any answers are likely to be a subset of those for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/88/what-would-it-mean-to-disprove-church-turing-thesis even if the precise wording might be useful to keep around for searches.

Comment: @András: you are right. I wrote and deleted an answer, after I realized it was already an answer to the question you mentioned.

Comment: @Kaveh: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/88/what-would-it-mean-to-disprove-church-turing-thesis/90#90 links to the Wikipedia article, presumably that is why Alessandro deleted the answer.